# Diffrence between textfieldshouldendediting and textfieldDidendediting in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uitextfield

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Diffrence between textfieldshouldendediting and textfieldDidendediting in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12262909/diffrence-between-textfieldshouldendediting-and-textfielddidendediting-in-iphone)

What is the diffrence between `textFieldShouldendEditing` and `textfieldDidEndEditing` methods? and when will use these methods.

Comment: The documentation is there to be read: [UITextFieldDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From documentation:

```
textFieldShouldendEditing:
```

> This method is called when the text field is asked to resign the first responder status. This might occur when your application asks the text field to resign focus or when the user tries to change the editing focus to another control. Before the focus actually changes, however, the text field calls this method to give your delegate a chance to decide whether it should.

```
textfieldDidEndEditing:
```

> This method is called after the text field resigns its first responder status. You can use this method to update your delegate’s state information. For example, you might use this method to hide overlay views that should be visible only while editing.

So, the `textFieldShouldendEditing:`method will be called before `textfieldDidEndEditing:`method

Answer (score 1):

`textFieldShouldendEditing` will call when your textField is about to end edit mode. It has a BOOL return type. If you set `return NO` than your textField will not be resignFirstResponder and remain in editing mode and `textfieldDidEndEditing` is not going to call.

while `textfieldDidEndEditing` this is method which tell you that your text field not in editing mode and your keyboard is down.

For more details plz refer [UITextFieldDelegate Protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html)
Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

**textFieldDidEndEditing:** 
is called when the text field resigns as the first responder. So you can then get the value entered from the user.

**textFieldShouldendEditing:** is used to check if the key entered by the user should be displayed on the text field or not. So if you return NO the key is not displayed.
Imagine a label where you want to restrict the number of letters entered. You can use the above to check how many characters are entered and if they have reached the limit, return the value `NO` which basically doesn't take any new key strokes.

You can check the [reference doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html) for more info.